# Sending an IG Message when Someone Follows My Page

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, webhooks, instagram-api

I'm trying to create a bot that will send my new followers a message on Instagram when they follow me. I'm using Facebook's graph API and webhook to enable this. I want to know if this is possible as I'm having issues with the webhook. The workflow is
1. a webhook on my page that will listen to any new follow requests
2. grab that follower's information
3. send that follower a message.

Currently, my Instagram account is linked with a FB page and I've been able to add webhooks to that page. However, I don't know how I can add a webhook to listen to my IG follower information that is linked to my FB page.

Comment: Doesn't matter if you can listen to IG follower information. Because there is no way to spam users with messages.

Comment: @wizkid, what do you mean? You can send messages to people with the new Instagram Messaging API https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/instagram/

Comment: That allows you to respond to messages. It doesn't allow you to randomly spam people

Comment: @WizKid, there's an app called GrowSocial (https://growsoci.al/#features) that allows you to send automatic DM's to current followers and new followers. They've been able to find a way to do it.